# Python3 Objects All Could Not Print Anything

Tags: django, django-models

I start a shell with the below command:

```
python manage.py shell
```

Then I import my models called Port and User with the below command:

```
from blog.models import Post
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

After then I have implemented below few commands:

```
user = User.objects.get(username='ola')
Post.objects.create(author = user, title = 'Sample title', text = 'Test')
```

At the last, I have implemented below command:

```
Post.objects.all()
```

However, I could only get the string as below picture
[image: What I got form command Post.objects.all()]

Could anyone help me with this? Why couldn't I get the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set `__str__` method in your model:

```
class Post(...):
    title = models.CharField(...)
    # other fields

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Now usually it will print the value of `title` field.

By default it gives: `f"{self.model} object ({self.id})"`

Comment: Thanks for the help bro! Actually, I had already added the `__str__` in my model. However, it didn't work is that I missed the Tab in front of the `def`.